# How to implement __delitem__ to handle all possible slice scenarios?

Tags: python, slice

I work on a class with and embedded list.

```
class a:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.l = [1] * n
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.l[i]
    def __delitem__(self, i):
        print type(i)
        print i
```

I want to use the `del` operator with the full syntax of slices:

```
p = a(10)
del p[1:5:2]
```

The `__delitem__` receives a `slice` object if the parameter is not a single index. How can I use the `slice` object to iterate through the specified elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `indices` method of the slice object will, given the length of the sequence, provide the canonical interpretation of the slice that you can feed to `xrange`:

```
def __delitem__(self, item):
    if isinstance(item, slice):
        for i in xrange(*item.indices(len(self.l))):
            print i
    else:
        print operator.index(item)
```

The use of `slice.indices` makes sure that you get correct behavior in cases pointed out by [Dunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986410/how-to-implement-delitem-to-handle-all-possible-slice-scenarios#comment17615204_12986434). Also note that you can pass the slice object to `list.__delitem__`, so if you only need to do some preprocessing and delegate actual deletion to the underlying list, a "naive" `del self.l[i]` will in fact work correctly.

`operator.index` will make sure that you get an early exception if your `__delitem__` receives a non-slice object that cannot be converted to an index.

Answer (score 3):

`slice` objects have `start`, `stop`, and `step` attributes that you can use to get each of those components. For example:

```
def __delitem__(self, i):
    if isinstance(i, slice):
        for j in xrange(i.start, i.stop, i.step):
            print j
    else:
        print i
```

Comment: It's important to point out that if the slice is incomplete (i.e., it has implied portions) the corresponding attributes of the slice object will be `None`.

Comment: This will produce erroneous indices if `stop > len(self)`. It also won't work for some combinations of negative indexes/steps. eg `slice(-10,5,-1)` if `len(p) > 11`

Comment: @jpm yes, this is what I ran into. However the answer gave the hint to proceed.

Comment: @Dunes I added an answer that covers these cases in a reasonably elegant way.